# c# cancelar y reiniciar Tareas (Tasks)

Tags: c#, windows-forms, asynctask

Tengo una aplicación Windows Forms. En función de los parametros que elija el usuario el proceso puede ser muy largo, asi que se permite cancelar, elegir otros parametros y volver a lanzar el proceso.
Consigo parar el proceso, pero no volverlo a lanzar, puesto que el token de cancelación queda activo. Tampoco puedo hacer Dispose() del token puesto que a la siguiente vez no existe.
La solución que me pareció lógica sería crear el token a nivel de la clase y luego instanciarlo cuando se pulsa el boton de empezar(este boton hace de switch empezar/cancelar) , pero esto no funciona; no da error, pero el proceso no para. Segun el debug, el token queda como true en el hilo principal y en false en el otro hilo.
¿como se hace para poder pulsar el boton una vez cancelada la tarea?
nota,- He visto ejemplos que tienen muy buena pinta, pero que he probado y no funcionan. P. ej.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58934233/c-sharp-how-to-stop-a-async-task-on-button-click
La clase Cancel.Tok.Source tiene que definirse e instanciarse a nivel de clase, de otra forma no funciona, no se porqué

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private CancellationTokenSource miToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
    //
    //Evento pulsar el botón
    private  void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //miToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken tokenCancelar = miToken.Token;
        if (button1.Text == "Cancelar")
        {
            miToken.Cancel();
            button1.Text = "Comenzar";
        }
        else
        {
            button1.Text = "Cancelar";
            Task.Run(() =>  ProcesoLento(tokenCancelar));
        }
    }
    void ProcesoLento(CancellationToken tc)
    {
        for (int cont = 0; cont <= 1000; cont++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            if (tc.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                return;
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno pues ya lo he conseguido. Hay cosas en C# que creo que se han hecho pensando en el compilador y no en los millones de usuarios, no le veo la lógica a ciertas cosas por ningún sitio y hay que saberselas de memoria o estas perdido.

Gracias a un magnifico tutorial que encontré en https://www.codeproject.com , me he empapado de todo este asunto de tareas sincronas, asincronas, como funcionan y todas sus posibilidades.

Este es el resultado . He hecho un programa muy sencillito de WinForms con un progress bar, un Label y un Button que hace switch entre comenzar y cancelar el proceso.
Por alguna razón que no entiendo, cuando lanzo un ThrowIfCancellationRequested , me salta un error de excepción no controlada por el usuario, pese a tener un try Catch que contempla eso. Bueno esto ya para otro día
[image: Formulario Windows]

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private delegate void ActualizarGUI(int x, int y);
    private CancellationTokenSource cts;
    private Task miTarea;
         public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (button1.Text == "Cancelar")  // solo para cancelación , se lanza y se sale del metodo sin ejecutar nada
        {
            Cancelar();
            return;
        }
        //  comienza el proceso
        int duracion = 100;
        int dormir = 100;
        progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
        progressBar1.Maximum = duracion;
        this.cts?.Cancel(); // el interrogrante antes de punto, previene que sea nulo
        this.cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        try
        {

            button1.Text = "Cancelar";
            this.miTarea = Task.Run(() => ProcesoLento(duracion,dormir,cts.Token), cts.Token);
            await this.miTarea;
            button1.Text = "Comenzar";

        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            label1.Text = "Cancelada";
        }
        this.miTarea.Dispose();
        this.miTarea = null;

    }
    void Cancelar()
    {
        this.cts?.Cancel();
    }
    void  ProcesoLento(int duracion,int dormir,CancellationToken tc)
    {
        ActualizarGUI Progreso = new ActualizarGUI(ActualizarProgreso);// instancia el delegado con el nombre del metodo a ejecutar
        for (int cont = 0; cont <= duracion; cont++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(dormir);
            this.Invoke(Progreso, new object[] { cont, duracion }); // delegado y array con los parametros del delegado
            if (tc.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                //tc.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                return;
            }
        }

    }
    void ActualizarProgreso(int avance,int total)
    {
        
        progressBar1.Value=avance;
        label1.Text = avance.ToString() + "/" + total.ToString();
    }
}
```

}